# Spectral Analysis vs. Spectral Line Analysis

Tags: frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density

We usually talk about "spectral analysis" but some resources ([this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016516849390090W) or [this doc](http://www.alma.inaf.it/images/Moments.pdf)) talk about "spectral line analysis".

Does this make sense to you, i.e. are the 2 fields actually different or the 2 names refer to the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spectrum analysis is more general: it involves looking at the entire spectrum of a given signal.

Spectral line analysis assumes that the spectrum contains several peaks (lines) of interest at specific frequencies.  The aim then is to find the precise frequency, magnitude, and phase of those peaks (lines).

Answer (score 1):

Just to enrich the previous answer, the line spectrum is defined in *Stoica, P., & Moses, R. (2005). Spectral analysis of signals. Prentice Hall. p.144* as associated to signals of the form:
$$
y(t)=x(t)+e(t)
$$
where $x(t)$ is a sinusoidal noise-free signal defined as $x(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_k e^{i(\omega _k t+\phi _k )} $ and $e(t)$ is circular white noise with power $\sigma^2$.

So a line spectrum equals $\sigma^2$ everywhere except for some specific frequencies, hence the name *line* spectrum.

See e.g. the following picture from [Michael Richmond](http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys301/lectures/doppler/doppler.html): [image: Radial velocity of a galaxy]

UPDATE : an extra reference explaining the different types of spectra is p.142 in *Percival, D. B., & Walden, A. T. (1998). Spectral analysis for physical applications*.

In this reference, *line spectras* are called *discrete* or *purely discrete*.

Comment: Nice addition!!!